# Overloading operator +

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following code inside `Movie` class:

```
Movie& operator+ (const Movie& other);
```

Now I want to overload this a few times, say `MOVIE1 + MOVIE2 + MOVIE3 + MOVIE4`

When I try to do:

```
Movie& operator+ (const Movie& left, const Movie& right);
```

It gives me error :

```
must take zero or one argument
```

While searching I saw a few solutions, none of which worked for me.

Comment: Is the second version declared inside `Movie`? It should be a non-member function.

Comment: And it seems very strange to return a reference from `operator+`. Are you sure you don't want to return by value?

Comment: Im not sure what is the difference.. refernce would work out wouldn't it?

Comment: Actually you don't need overloaded `operator+()`... first definition handles the condition you are talking about... think why `Movie&` is returned...

Comment: and I tried to implement

Movie& operator+ (const Movie& left, const Movie& right);

in a different class which includes movie, still doesn't work

Comment: @aviadm71 what would you be returning a reference to? An automatic variable? `operator+` should be declared outside of any class, it should be a non-member function.

Comment: a simple `operator+(const Movie& other)` is all you need to be able to write `movie1+movie2+movie2...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to overload the operator to add many objects, this is already handled by the `operator+` you have. You should only change it to return a value not a reference :

```
struct A {
    int value;
    A() : value(1) {}
    A operator+(const A& other){
        A result;
        result.value = this->value + other.value;
        return result;
    }
}; 

int main() {
    A a,b,c;
    A d = a + b + c;
    std::cout << d.value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this one i guess compiles.. but does it return the right answer?

Comment: @aviadm71 [yes it does](https://ideone.com/7LIvEW). Why do you think it should not?

Comment: @aviadm71 just think of all the pod types, they do not need to provide all kinds of overloads, but you can write `int a = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5` for an arbitrary number of operands

Answer (score 3):

You don't need anything special to chain additions, you just need a correct operator overload.

The best way to implement `operator+` is to implement `operator+=` for your class, then write `operator+` as a non-member function in terms of `operator+=`. This gets you two operators for the price of one, lowers code duplication and treats left and right arguments symmetrically with respects to implicit conversions.

An issue with your implementation is that you return a reference to a `Movie`. This would require either dynamically allocating the `Movie` and remembering to delete it (inefficient, error prone), returning a reference to a local (undefined behaviour) or having some more complex system in place (unnecessary). You should just return by value.

Here's what an implementation could look like:

```
class Movie {
public:
    Movie& operator+= (const Movie& rhs) { 
        m_data += rhs.m_data;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int m_data; //assume some data
};

Movie operator+ (Movie lhs, const Movie& rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I wrote twice as much without saying as much and threw it away.

Answer (score 0):

You don't require overloaded definition of `operator+()`.

```
Movie MOVIE5 = MOVIE1+MOVIE2+MOVIE3+MOVIE4;
```

To understand you can expand this as

```
Movie MOVIE5 = MOVIE1+MOVIE2+MOVIE3.opertor+(MOVIE4);
```

`operator+MOVIE3.opertor+(MOVIE4)` returns `Movie object`, which is then added with `MOVIE2 object` and their result will in turn added to with `MOVIE1` finally returning result in `MOVIE5 object`

Answer (score 0):

The first definition:

```
Movie& operator+ (const Movie& other);
```

already allows you to chain the `operator +` in a statement like the one you want to write :

```
MOVIE1+MOVIE2+MOVIE3+MOVIE4; // assumes all those variable are of type Movie
```

The reason it works is that the operator returns a non-const reference to `Movie` (`Movie&` in the function declaration). This return value becomes the left operand of the next `operator +`.

`MOVIE1+MOVIE2+MOVIE3;` statement is equivalent to `(MOVIE1+MOVIE2)+MOVIE3;`. We can see it is composed of two expression (whose operator is `+` for both). The first expression evaluated is `MOVIE1+MOVIE2`. The return value becomes the left operand for the second addition, with `MOVIE3` as the right operand.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by TartanLlama, you probably want to change the signature of your first method to:

```
Movie operator+ (const Movie& other); // return a value instead of a reference
```

Because you could be returning a reference to a local object, which will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: What will the operator return a reference to?

Comment: @TartanLlama Thanks for catching that, let's assume there is not a clever cache mechanism behind this `operator +` (but then, what does it mean to sum up movies ;)

Answer (score 0):

Operators can be chained normally: if you have operator `+` defined for adding two `Widget`s and returning a `Widget`, you can add as many `Widgets` with it as you like. The reason is simple:

```
a + b + c + d
```

is parsed as

```
((a + b) + c) + d
```

However, there's something wrong with your operator declaration: you're returning a *reference* to a `Movie`. That makes no sense for an operator like `+`, which creates a new value rather than modify an existing one. You should be creating a separate `Movie` object inside the operator, and returning it by value.

Generally, the best way of handling operators like this is to implement the operation&assignment variant in class, and building the binary operator as a non-member function on top of that. Something like this:

```
class Movie
{
  // ...
  Movie& operator+= (const Movie &rhs)
  {
    //somehow add rhs to this
    return *this;
  }
  // ...
};

inline Movie operator+ (const Movie &lhs, const Movie &rhs)
{
  Movie result = lhs;
  result += rhs;
  return result;
}
```

There's one more point: though. What does it mean to add two movies together in the first place? Overloading operators for the sake of shorter syntax for some arbitrary, unituitive operation leads to unreadable and hence unmaintainable and hence **bad** code.

Unless you're building a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) (which you're probably not), I'd stick with named functions for the sake of maintainability.

Answer (score -2):

The `+` operator is a so called `binary` operator (as opposed to `unary`). That means it takes exactly two arguments: 
`"left hand side" <operator> "right hand side"`

Only non-member binary operators take two arguments.

As the left hand side in member-methods is always the current object `this`, all member binary operators take only one argument.

That is the reason you won't find a solution for this.

What you can do instead is to return an array of movies.

Comment: Non-member binary operators take two arguments.

Comment: how would returning an array of movies help?

Comment: I guess what the OP tries to accomplish is to have a list of movies. So that is an array (or std::list or QList or what ever lib you are using).